# How to display current working copy version of an hg repository on a PHP page

Tags: php, mercurial

I use Mercurial for most of my projects and when I deploy a web site, I simply just do an `hg clone` on the production server and `hg pull -u` from there. What I'd like to do is add a small snippet to my site's footer which displays the current revision number (both decimal and hex) as well as perhaps the current branch. Stack Overflow and BitBucket both do a variation of what I'm looking for.

I briefly tried parsing the output of `exec('hg summary')`, but I ran into a couple permissions problems before wondering if there was any better way to do it. Is there a better way, or is `exec` my best option?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use a post-update hook to put the information in a file.  In the site's `.hg/hgrc` you'd put something like this:

```
[hooks]
post-update = hg id --rev > VERSION ; hg id --id >> VERSION
```

then you can access that file from inside your php.  You'll still need to make sure that the user running the `hg pull -u` trusts the hgrc file and that the VERSION file has permissions such that the webserver can read it.

Comment: A good description of the revision can obtained with something like `hg log -r . --template "v{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-{node|short}\n"`.  This returns a string like "v1.0.0-2-5e51254a" (i.e. 2 commits after tag `1.0.0` with changeset id `5e51254a`.

Comment: Good answer - I like it. Doesn't rely on `exec`, easy enough to implement. Thanks!

Comment: `hg id -r` expects an argument, I guess you meant `-n`?

Comment: Right you are @tommyd, though Tim Henigan's form is better yet.